# Why don't the "deemed helpful" flag totals add up in my flag history?

Tags: support, flag-history

As per below image my flag history says **186 deemed helpful** in list and again its showing **1 deemed helpful** in last so my confusion is why it is not **showing 187 flags as deemed helpful** , and why it is showing in two separate sections...

[image]

Comment: Spam flags are counted separately.

Comment: but its not spam flag...

Comment: Yes it is; *1 post marked spam*, and that one flag was helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spam and offensive flags are counted separately.

You’ve raised 230 moderator attention flags, and you raised 1 spam flag. Of the former, 186 where helpful, of the latter, 1 was helpful (i.e. all).

The two tables are separate. The numbers in the first group also add up; 36 + 186 + 4 + 4 = 230. So do the totals in the second group.

Once upon a time Stack Overflow only had spam / offensive flags. Moderator attention flags were added at a later time. Spam / offensive flags also have different effects from moderator attention flags (enough such flags auto-delete a post, each carries an automatic downvote, and if a post is deleted, the OP receives a hefty 100 point fine). As such they are tracked separately, too.